# python dll return value is wrong

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I have made a dll which contains the code:

```c
#pragma once

extern double __declspec(dllexport) add(double a, double b);
extern double __declspec(dllexport) dif(double a, double b);

#include "testdll.h"

double add(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}

double dif(double a, double b)
{
    return a - b;
}
```

The python code which calls the add function:

```
    a = ctypes.c_double(1);
    b = ctypes.c_double(2);
    mydll = ctypes.CDLL('testDll.dll');
    mydll.restype = ctypes.c_double;
    ret  = mydll.AddNumbers(a, b);
```

The problem is that the add function doesnt return a+b but a screwd up value: 2619340

Please help

Comment: strangely it works correctly for integers. Only doubles make the problem...

Comment: - changed the code not to use a python function to get the result. The result is still wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The return type is `double`, so you should set `restype` like so:

```
hllDll.add.restype = ctypes.c_double
hllDll.add.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ctypes.c_double(1);
b = ctypes.c_double(2);
mydll = ctypes.CDLL('testDll.dll');
mydll.AddNumbers.restype = ctypes.c_double;
ret  = mydll.AddNumbers(a, b);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.